# Access Windows Guest From Mac OS Host VirtualBox

Tags: macos, windows-10, virtualbox, nat

I have problem to access web server on my Guest Machine from Host Machine.
So I have Mac OS Catalina as Host Machine and Windows 10 as Guest Machine, also use VirtualBox v6.0.14

I configure my guest os with 2 adapter as follow:

1. NAT adapter (I use this adapter to access internet)
   [image: NAT Config]
2. Host Only Adapter (I use this adapter to communicate between host and guests)
   [image: Host Only Config]

Right now, I can access internet from guest machine, so we can assume first adapter (NAT) is work.
I also can ping host machine from guest machine, but I cannot ping guest machine from machine (I think there is problem with second configuration which is host only adapter configuration)

From the configuration I got IP config like this:

1. vboxnet0 configuration on virtual box
   [image: vboxnet0 adapter]
   [image]
2. IP Config on Host Machine (Mac OS Catalina)
   [image]
3. IP Config on Guest Machine (Windows 10)
   [image]

I can ping host machine from guest machine as follow:
[image]

But I can not ping guest machine from host machine (also can not open web server on guest machine from host machine)
[image]

Anyone can help me to find the solution, to access guest machine from host machine with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Independent of firewalls or other considerations, there are two basic ways gain access to a VirtualBox VM Guest hosting e.g. a web server.

The first option is to add a bridged network adapter (this is the simplest solution). This will add a virtual adapter for the Guest that can be accessed like any normal machine on the network (i.e. via a discrete local IP address ex. assigned by your router's DHCP).

The second option is to use the existing NAT adapter's *Advanced* options to configure port forwarding, like you would on a router. That is, you would take e.g. port 80, and tell VirtualBox to pass requests for that port to your Guest.

Comment: I have try use Bridged Network, but still I cannot ping the guest machine from host.